# Can you train an SVM on only SIFT Descriptors?

Tags: opencv, svm, sift

Does it make sense to only feed SIFT descriptors corresponding to an image label into a support vector machine? I have extracted 500 SIFT descriptors, with 128 vectors each. Then I found medians of the 128 vectors to only have 500 median SIFT descriptor values per image. Those were fed into an SVM with corresponding labels. However, I am wondering theoretically if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it and it make sense. it was the benchmark method before the rise of 2012 Alexnet.

[image]

There are many opensource that use this already. see  https://www.vlfeat.org/

You are on the right track but only 15 years behind the current state of the art. The current state of the art are all varous LSTM CNN deep learning based approches.